# Android Audio Player Runtime Exception

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public class AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity extends Activity implements
        OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private ImageButton btnPlay;
    private ImageButton btnForward;
    private ImageButton btnBackward;
    private ImageButton btnNext;
    private ImageButton btnPrevious;
    private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
    private ImageButton btnRepeat;
    private ImageButton btnShuffle;
    private SeekBar songProgressBar;
    private TextView songTitleLabel;
    private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
    private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
    // Media Player
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    // Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
    private SongsManager songManager;
    private Utilities utils;
    private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int currentSongIndex = 0;
    private boolean isShuffle = false;
    private boolean isRepeat = false;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);

        // All player buttons
        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
        btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
        btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
        btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
        btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
        btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
        songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
        songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
        songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

        // Mediaplayer
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        songManager = new SongsManager();
        utils = new Utilities();

        // Listeners
        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

        // Getting all songs list
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

        // By default play first song
        playSong(0);

        /**
         * Play button click event plays a song and changes button to pause
         * image pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check for already playing
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Resume song
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Forward button click event Forwards song specified seconds
         * */
        btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
                if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()) {
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                } else {
                    // forward to end position
                    mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Backward button click event Backward song to specified seconds
         * */
        btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
                if (currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0) {
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
                } else {
                    // backward to starting position
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Next button click event Plays next song by taking currentSongIndex +
         * 1
         * */
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check if next song is there or not
                if (currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)) {
                    playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                } else {
                    // play first song
                    playSong(0);
                    currentSongIndex = 0;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Back button click event Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
         * */
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (currentSongIndex > 0) {
                    playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
                } else {
                    // play last song
                    playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Repeat button Enables repeat flag to true
         * */
        btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (isRepeat) {
                    isRepeat = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                } else {
                    // make repeat to true
                    isRepeat = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isShuffle = false;
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Shuffle button Enables shuffle flag to true
         * */
        btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (isShuffle) {
                    isShuffle = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                } else {
                    // make repeat to true
                    isShuffle = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isRepeat = false;
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Play list click event Launches list activity
         * which displays list of songs
         * */
        btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        PlayListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Receiving song index from playlist view and play the song
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
            // play selected song
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to play a song
     * 
     * @param songIndex
     *            - index of song
     * */
    public void playSong(int songIndex) {
        // Play song
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            // Displaying Song title
            String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
            songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

            // Changing Button Image to pause image
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

            // set Progress bar values
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);

            // Updating progress bar
            updateProgressBar();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update timer on seekbar
     * */
    public void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }

    /**
     * Background Runnable thread
     * */
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
            long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

            // Displaying Total Duration time
            songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""
                    + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
            // Displaying time completed playing
            songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""
                    + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

            // Updating progress bar
            int progress = (int) (utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration,
                    totalDuration));
            // Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
            songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

            // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

    /**
     * 
     * */
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromTouch) {

    }

    /**
     * When user starts moving the progress handler
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }

    /**
     * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(),
                totalDuration);

        // forward or backward to certain seconds
        mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

        // update timer progress again
        updateProgressBar();
    }

    /**
     * On Song Playing completed if repeat is ON play same song again if shuffle
     * is ON play random song
     * */
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

        // check for repeat is ON or OFF
        if (isRepeat) {
            // repeat is on play same song again
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else if (isShuffle) {
            // shuffle is on - play a random song
            Random rand = new Random();
            currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else {
            // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
            if (currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)) {
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            } else {
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }

}
```

This is the log cat error:

```
11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.musicplayer/com.androidhive.musicplayer.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)

11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)

11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)

11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)

11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)

11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)

11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

11-01 04:18:15.341: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
```

When I run my apps, my android apps turn to stop and I see this error in my log cat. I don't understand this error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: After trolling through the androidhive music player code a bit, it looks like it is looking for music files on your sdcard.  Do you have any music files on your sdcard?

Comment: yap o have@Michael Krause

Comment: looks like your songList size is zero. check the size of the song list.